# what are webhooks? what is its use?how can i use it in my woocommerce wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I would like to know the following things about the web-hook, 
1. Actually what are web-hooks and what is its functionality? 
2. I have a woo-commerce word-press site, how can i make use of the web-hook in my android app for my woocommerce sie? 
3. For integrating web-hooks in android application which have a woo-commerce site what all things i need to do?

Can anyone help me please..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you talking about PayPal webhooks or something (PayPal is in the tags)? Webhook implementations can vary quite a bit (just as APIs do). Maybe show us what you're trying to achieve exactly or otherwise elaborate on your question? Perhaps split 1, 2 and 3 to completely separate questions so you can get clear and targeted answers.

Comment: actually i would like to know what is the functionality of the webhook? i have a woocommerce, and its android app. but when i am parsing the api of the webhook it returns in error. I think it is because i didn't add any webhooks anywhere..

Comment: The basic function of webhooks is to allow acting upon triggers in an external application. Essentially your Woocommerce installation should fire requests to a given target location which will then act on the requests. E.g. a purchase is done in Woocommerce, which sends a POST request to 123.456.78.90 IP with wanted data, and then the service at 123.456.68.90 does some action depending on the given POST data. As far as I know, Woocommerce doesn't have webhooks "out-of-the-box" so you'd probably have to implement those yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From [WooThemes WebHooks Documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/webhooks/),

> What are Webhooks? 
>   A Webhook is essentially an event
>   notification sent to a URL of your choosing. Users can configure them
>   to cause events on one site to invoke behaviour on another.
>
> Webhooks are therefore very useful for integrating with third party
>   services and other external API that support them.

The site goes on to explain how to manage web hooks and gives some examples that could be useful.